# Getting inset box-shadow to cover text within a containing div?

Tags: html, css

I am having the toughest time getting this inset box-shadow (#shadow-overlay) to cover the text inside of #text-container. I have done my research and tried using z-index with position:relative/absolute, even making a separate div and using that as the overlay. I still can't get it to work though! Basically, I want the inset box-shadow on the bottom of #shadow-overlay to cover the text within #text-container. Can you guys help me out? Thanks!

CSS: http://pastebin.com/QdNhCc9H
HTML: http://pastebin.com/D3tYKXky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add `z-index: -2` to `#content-box`
2. Add `z-index: -1` to `#text-container`
3. Remove `z-index: 2` from `#shadow-overlay`

You may have to play with the overlay sizing/positioning to prevent it from covering the scrollbar.